# How to create an account using the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, user-accounts

With the Stack Exchange Android app, I can visit any Stack Exchange site. I have all options, such as upvoting, but trying to make use of them ends with the error message, that the token is not authorized for that site. However, I can't find an option for creating an account on that site.

Is that operation possible from the Stack Exchange Android app, or I must go to the site with a mobile browser?

Comment: You could probably turn this into a [feature-request]. I don't think there's a duplicate of it.

Comment: This is one of the last missing features before we call the app "beta". So it won't be too long.

Comment: As the mobile apps are no longer supported I'm closing this as no longer reproducable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an account is not possible from the app as of version 0.1.77.

You will have to use the browser to create an account.

Comment: Any source for this?